What is the difference between "Swift Testing with XCTest UI Tests" and "XCTest for Unit and UI Tests" in Xcode 16
When creating a new project in Xcode 16, I noticed that there are now two options for testing system: "Swift Testing with XCTest UI Tests" and "XCTest for Unit and UI Tests". What are the differences between them two?
Can anyone tell me which one to use for any particular purposes?

Swift has a new framework for unit testing named Testing

It's not very well phrased. What it means is (in the reverse order from the order you listed them):

Tests, where XCTest is used for UI testing and unit testing.
Tests, where XCTest is used for UI testing, but the new Swift Testing DSL is used for unit testing.

So your choice is merely between whether you want to use the old XCTest or the new Swift Testing to write your unit tests. Basically, do you like typing a bunch of verbose mysterious function names that start with XCT, or do you want to write tests in natural-looking Swift?
